# Openstack/Nova : No route to host when I'm trying to ssh instance

Tags: ssh, instance, openstack, devstack

I run a little dev vagrant box with Openstack installed on it thanks to devstack. Everything runs pretty good, but I can't manage to connect through ssh to my new instance. 
When I try ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa cirros@10.0.0.2 I get the following message :

```
ssh connect to host 10.0.0.2 port 22: No route to host
```

My security group rules are fine but I'm not able to find the problem.

Comment: What are the rules in your iptables on the host?

Comment: Port 22 and IPMI of course but I think it's just a problem with the meta data server. Sometimes I can't connect to it thus my problem, and when it works I can ping and ssh my VM. It looks like it's totally random.... Strange

Comment: you can't ssh to your instance during the instance booting until sshd daemon started. and this should have nothing to do with meta data server.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: As I can remember I had some problem to ping my VM because of some package I didn't get.

Comment: hey @MaximeHeckel did you try to ssh through Floating IP?

Comment: "No route to host" means just that - the VM's IP address is not routable from your machine. Are you trying to SSH from the host or from the vagrant box?

Answer (score 3):

A useful Resource is the [RDO Website](https://www.rdoproject.org/).

From [Networking](https://www.rdoproject.org/Networking):

> Verify that traffic to port 22 and ICMP traffic of any type (-1:-1) is allowed in the default security group.
>   Verify that you can ping and SSH the host where the instance is running
>   From the host where you are attempting to connect to your instance, verify that network traffic is being correctly routed to the compute node in question.

```
ip netns list
# Identify virtual router to which your subnet is connected
ip netns exec qrouter-YOUR-OVSROUTER-ID ping YOUR-INSTANCE-IP
# IP address and qrouter ID correspond to the network namespace and private IP address for instance
```

If that is working your network is working fine.
You can try restarting the following services:

```
sudo systemctl restart neutron-metadata-agent.service 
sudo systemctl restart neutron-dhcp-agent.service
```